# Выделение ячеек в GridView

Tags: android, gridview

Добрый день!

У меня в GridView при выделении ячейки или нажатии на неё не снимается выделение с уже выделенных. Как сделать так, чтобы при выделении ячейки выделялась только она, или хотя бы строка? Может, нужно какое-то свойство задать?

Answer (score 0):

Код к сожалению сейчас предоставить не смогу, но вся идея заключается в переопределению адаптера 
GridView.Adapter = new MyAdapter(sourceItems);

и уже в нем переписываете функцию получения выбранной ячейки (что-то вроде

```
override long GetItem(int position)
{
// все элементы, с ID не равным position установить как не выбранные.
})
```

**Но в лучшей практикой будет кончено связывание (Binding) с ViewModel** и переписать для всей коллекции sourceItem свойство "не выбранно". Тогда нужно будет просто правильно настроить адаптер на использование этого свойства.

Comment: А как установить "как не выбранное"?

Comment: @Александр как буду с компьютера, дам пример